# Where do I ask thematic database related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

For example, where are open access military conflict databases? I want to make worldwide annual summary on military conflicts intensity.

Is it OpenData? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you already asked it there. then why this question?

Comment: i might have been wrong

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the What is on-topic on [OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it says:

> - where to [find any kind of open data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request)

The link suggests you tag these questions with [data-request].

In the tag [excerpt](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/data-request/info) you'll find guidance to read [How a good data-request question should look](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look) by [Nicolas Raoul](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/users/754/nicolas-raoul). It's main points (paraphrased) for making a successful data-request question are:

> 1. **Data**: Explain exactly what data you are looking for.
> 2. **Context**: What are you actually trying to achieve.
> 3. **Region**: Say what country/region your question applies to, if applicable.
> 4. **License**: Say what licenses are acceptable.
> 5. **Format**: Say what numeric units and data/file format you want.
> 6. **Authority**: What kind of organization do you want the data to come from?
> 7. **Requirements**: List all other requirements you have.
> 8. **Non-answers**: If you have tried a few obvious candidates before (or while) asking the question but they don't fit, then explain why.

Do know that on most Stack Exchange site asking for finding off-site resources is off-topic. Those sites that do allow it often have strict guidance to prevent questions that turn into a bad collection of google links. When uncertain post post on their Meta first.