# Unable to edit tags in landscape mode

Tags: bug, android-app

Trying to add tag on [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297856/339911) in landscape mode leads to clearing site section. I.e. impossible to edit post. Video for details:

> [image]

- App Version: 1.0.94
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1710300506712)

Comment: FYI imgur will support gif.

Comment: @SagarV I know, but uploading from URL gives me ["format is not supported error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJUo1.png). Uploading from my PC ends with timeout error.

Comment: is this when modifying the tags while submitting a new question or editing a post?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi while editing already existing.

Comment: hmm no rero on my Pixel running Android 7.1.2, and I'm seeing a 404 for your image.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi for which image?

Comment: The... only image attached in the post? All I see under "Video for details:" is a "404 - image not found! The url you enter is invalid or expired. ezgif.com"

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi now you can see.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll try some more to repro this and figure out what's going on.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I have posted [about ~30 bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911+%5Bandroid-app%5D+is%3Aq) tagged [android-app] here. You will have something to do :)

Comment: haha thank you for the bug postings, trust me my issue isn't a lack of things to do :) I'll do my best!

Comment: Uhh... no repro on v1.0.95 beta, but I don't know if it's already fixed or no repro on Nexus 5, Android 7.1.2...

Comment: @Disney bug is still present in 1.0.95 for me.